why other apps treat a post processed clip from a video with the same length of original video but it actually is much more less?
I have this script which processes some videos and chops them into clips. So far so good with the script but I don't understand why does other apps treat the shorter clip the same length as the original video, but instead it should be just as many seconds as I want the clip to be.
This is the relevant code which I currently have.
try:
                (
                    ffmpeg
                    .input(video_path, ss=start_time, t=snippet_duration)
                    .output(output_file, vcodec='h264_nvenc', **{
                        'metadata': 'duration={}'.format(snippet_duration),
                        'video_track_timescale': 90000
                    })
                    .run(overwrite_output=True, capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
                )

            except ffmpeg.Error as e:
                tqdm.write(f"Error processing snippet {i + 1}: {e.stderr.decode('utf-8')}")
                continue

